# Number of ways to distribute $n$ distinguishable balls into $k$ distinguishable boxes such that no box is empty

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know that the formula for that is $k! \cdot S(n, k)$ and I have no problem in understanding that. What is troubling me is that if I count it in the following way I get a different answer.

Fill all the boxes with one ball. There are $nPk$ ways of doing that (assuming $n$ is greater than $k$). Then fill the remaining boxes as one would do a for the case when boxes can be empty. There are $k^{n-k}$ ways of doing that. So the result should be the product of these two. Why isn't this compatible with the real answer? Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that it incorrectly applies significance as to which ball was the "*guaranteed*" or "*first*" ball placed in each box.

Take for extreme case $3$ distinguishable balls and **one** box.  According to your mistaken formula, you would have counted $3$ possible outcomes... clearly seen as $1$ was the first ball placed in the box followed by the other two, $2$ was the first ball placed in the box then the others, or $3$ being placed in the box then the others.

Correcting the count here would be difficult since the number of balls actually placed in each box varies so the number of times we overcounted each scenario is possibly different for each overall scenario.  As such, it is best to completely rethink the approach and do as the book suggested using stirling numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The Stirling N. 2nd kind intervene when you are distributing $n$ distinguishable
items into $k$ distinguishable non-empty **subsets** : i.e. when the order into each bin is not considered.

Your approach is instead for distributing the n distinguishabe items into $k$ 
distinguishable non-empty **x-tuples**: i.e. the order into each bin is considered.

Example $n=3 , \; k=2$

$(1,2\,|\; 3),(1,3\,|\; 2),(2,3\,|\; 1)$ and inverting the bins $= 6$ ways $=2! {3 \brace 2}$

$(1,2\,|\; 3),(2,1\,|\; 3),(1,3\,|\; 2),(3,1\,|\; 2),(2,3\,|\; 1)(3,2\,|\; 1)$ and inverting the bins $=12$ ways $=n(n-1)k^{n-k}$